# Using public synonyms inside oracle materialized views

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, synonym

Is it possible to have public synonims inside materialized view query?

Comment: Yes I did, getting: ERROR at line 1: ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid; but If I run the query for the same user, it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

> "getting: ERROR at line 1: ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer
>   valid; but If I run the query for the same user, it runs fine"

That message means the synonym references an object which isn't in scope.  This can happen when the underlying object is dropped, or if the name is misspelled.  It can also happen if the object is in another schema and the owner revokes our privileges.

As your query runs normally, we can rule out the first couple of reasons.  So your problem is the permissions on the object the synonym points to.

I think your user has been granted rights through a role.  That allows us to use the object in queries.  However we cannot build database objects - stored procedures, views, materiliazed views - using those permissions.  We need the privilege to be directly granted to the user.  This is just the way the Oracle security model works.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try. You need to be granted the correct permissions obviously but it seems to work. I can only guess that your problem is your synonym not the materialized view.

```
create table tmp_test as
 select level as id, 'something' as blah
   from dual
connect by level <= 100;

Table created.


alter table tmp_test
  add constraint pk_tmp_test
      primary key (id)
      using index;

Table altered.


create materialized view log on tmp_test with primary key;

Materialized view log created.


create or replace public synonym testing123 for tmp_test;

Synonym created.


create materialized view working
refresh fast on demand
as
select *
from testing123;

Materialized view created.


select *
  from working
 where rownum < 11
       ;

        ID BLAH
---------- ---------
         1 something
         2 something
         3 something
         4 something
         5 something
         6 something
         7 something
         8 something
         9 something
        10 something

10 rows selected.
```